# Can I omit self when accessing instance variables in closure of map or reduce method?

Tags: ios, swift

I know I should use self in closure to access instance variables and Xcode shows error if I don't, but I didn't get error when I omitted self in closure of reduce method.
 Can I omit self in that case?

case A

```
gridsCount = (0..<collectionView!.numberOfSections()).reduce(0) { [weak self] (sum, section) -> Int in
   return sum + self.gridsInSection(section)
}
```

case B

```
gridsCount = (0..<collectionView!.numberOfSections()).reduce(0) { (sum, section) -> Int in
   return sum + gridsInSection(section)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason why you can omit `self` in the block lays in the existence of `@noescape` keyword in the function declaration:

> ```
> @warn_unused_result @rethrows func reduce<T>(initial: T, 
>    @noescape combine: (T, Self.Generator.Element) throws -> T) rethrows -> T
> ```

From [Xcode 6 release notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Xcode/Conceptual/RN-Xcode-Archive/Chapters/xc6_release_notes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016994-CH4-SW1):

> A new **@noescape** attribute may be used on closure parameters to functions. This indicates that the parameter is only ever called (or passed as an `@noescape` parameter in a call), which means that it cannot outlive the lifetime of the call.
>
> This enables some minor performance optimizations, but more importantly disables the `self.` requirement in closure arguments.

`@noescape` prevents `self` from being retained which is perfectly OK for using the closure to run that in a synchronous manner where you are sure that `self` is going to be alive in the course of the execution.

If your closure is going to be used as a *completion* block for some kind of asynchronous operations such as network requests, retrieving media files from gallery etc. where you heavily need `self` to be retained and stay alive inside the block, you don't mark it with `@noescape`.